# Mocked data not shown with Playwright

Tags: playwright

So I have a test like this. My problem is that the app does not get populated with this data even though I can see the correct data when I log the response. What am I doing wrong?

```
test('should show name', async ({ page }) => {
  page.on('response', (response) => {
    console.log(response.json().then((d) => console.log(d)));
  });
  await page.route('**/**', (route) =>
    route.fulfill({
     status: 200,
     contentType: 'application/json',
     body: '[{"id":1,"name":"John"}]',
   })
  );
  await page.goto('http://localhost:4200/names');
  await expect(page.locator('[data-test=name]')).toHaveText('John');
});
```

Comment: Lot of things unknown.What is your issue, error log.Which line.Why you are shoot Api request and then assert Ui.Explain and someone will help.

Comment: The issue is that I don't see the mocked data in the UI. There is no error apart from the one that text John doesn't exist because data is not rendered to the page.

Comment: If data is not render on page, you meean it is not present in the DOM. If that is correct first use hard wait to see will be present in some time, if not, I can not help you if it is present in DOM after some time, just put comment here, and we will solve it.

Comment: Having the same issue. Where you able so solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by passing the mocked response as a JavaScript object (not as JSON), deleting the quotes from the keys.

JSON string:

```
{"id":1,"name":"John"}
```

JavaScript object:

```
{id: 1, name: "John"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem recently, and it seems like it's an issue with the way the JSON string is formatted.  My solution was to just let JSON.stringify do that work for me:

```
route.fulfill({
  status: 200,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  body: JSON.stringify([{id: 1, name: "John"}]),
})
```